# How to emulate DEFAULT parameter in PDO when ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES is turned off?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I recently found out that `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` is set to true by default in PHP. This forum contains several posts which advise to set `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to false, so that is what I decided to do:

`$this->pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);`

It's a simple change, and none of the SQL queries that exist in the system should be affected by setting this attribute. After all, in a query `SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE column3 = ?` it shouldn't matter to the result of the query if the parameter is an actual parameter interpreted by the MySQL server or replaced by a (escaped) value provided by PDO.

However, today I came across a strange error. I have a query `ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN column INT NULL DEFAULT ?` which suddenly failed after setting the flag to not emulating query parameters.

I suspect that, for some reason, the `DEFAULT` value cannot be a parameter; it must be a hardcoded value instead. So when PDO emulates a statement, the MySQL server receives a query without noticing that the `DEFAULT` value was originally a parameter rather than a hardcoded value. Without emulation the MySQL server throws a syntax error, because it does not support a `DEFAULT` parameter value.

So my question is: is it possible to have PDO **not** emulate the query statement, but only emulate the `DEFAULT` value? Or should I attempt such an emulation myself when creating database schema adjustment queries that contain a `DEFAULT` clause?

Or should I simply turn `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` on again just to avoid to error?

Comment: What's the concrete error message? And yes, MySQL has some limitations on which statements permit parameterization. Table declarations do not really work with value binding nor expressions (much like the `LIKE` clause).

Comment: @mario the error message is about the invalidity of the syntax, because of the `?` character in the query which it does not understand (when statements aren't prepared).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such way.

If you strictly want to keep with emulation mode off, you can revert its state temporarily, when executing data modification queries and other statements for which your database does not support prepared statements. Taking emulation mode back to off after executing this particular query.

Or you can keep with emulation mode permanently. The only inconvenience here is inability to bind LIMIT parameters right in the execute().